# Modifying vertex coordinates not working

Tags: python, scripting

I’m trying to write coordinates into a vertex but somehow it doesn’t seem to take input

[image]

Every time this runs it prints some “2”s in the console as if it worked, but the next run they’re back to being 1 and -1 again.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj=bpy.context.edit_object
m=obj.data
bm=bmesh.from_edit_mesh(m)

print("---")

for i in range(0,8):

    v=bm.verts[i]

    co=obj.matrix_world@v.co
    print(co.x)
    co.x=2
    print(co.x)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(m)
```

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the problem is here:

```
co=obj.matrix_world@v.co
```

So here you have used an operator `@`. Like adding `+` or multiplying `*` it gets 2 entities, makes an operation with them and results a new entity. The `@` operator applies a transformation matrix on vector `v.co` and the result of this operation is saved in `co` property. So instead of linking the data it creates new data, so that assigning something to `co` doesn't make sense, because it holds a modified copy, not the link.

I suppose you can solve this like this:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
# import new module
import copy

obj=bpy.context.edit_object
m=obj.data
bm=bmesh.from_edit_mesh(m)

print("---")

for i in range(0,8):

    v=bm.verts[i]

    co=obj.matrix_world@v.co
    print(co.x)
    co.x=2
    print(co.x)
    
    # get a copy of transform matrix to be able to invert it:
    inverted = copy.copy(obj.matrix_world)
    inverted.invert()
    
    # now write property to the cube
    v.co = inverted @ co

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(m)
```

I have used inverted matrix to write coordinates back.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am very new to scripting so I just scavenged some code off of the web and put it together without really understanding much of it. I had no idea what the @ was. Could you point me to some systematic learning resources for Blender scripting? When I try to find resources the books are usually outdated and the online tutorials do not fully cover the fundamentals

Comment: The course on blender cloud should be helpful, and it gets updated then something is changed in API https://studio.blender.org/training/scripting-for-artists/

Comment: Fantastic! I appreciated it